# Binary Search Algorithm: Need help translating provided Pseudocode

Tags: c++, binary-search, pseudocode, sample

Doing a major programming assignment for a Data Abstraction and ADT class. It's a sorted linked list* type of "nested classes" referred to by pointers environment. The binary search algorithm is provided for us in the way of the pseudocode below.

> ```
> **ALGORITHM** *BinarySearch*(A[0...n-1], n, k)* //appropriate for get & remove
> //pre: A is sorted in ascending order, n is the number of items in the array
> // k is the item being searched for
> //post: if the search is successful the index of the match is returned( 1-based)
> //if the search is unsuccessful, -1 is returned
>
> f <-- 0 // 0-based indices used in this method
> I <-- n-1  /* personal note. I think its an I, the pdf could be an l though */
> /* personal note - I think the above is an I, pdf font could be an l though.
> --- secondly, the brackets in this pseudocode are bottom-half brackets.
> ---- i.e., they could be "floor" or "minimum"-based brackets of a kind */
>
> m <-- f + [(i-f)/2] // floor-brackets
>
> while f <= I do
> {
>    if (K = a[m]) // not-floor brackets, just subscript
>       return (m + 1)
>    else if ( K < A[m] ) // not-floor brackets, just subscript
>       I <-- m-1
>    else
>       f <-- m+1
>
>    m <-- f + [(I-f)/2] /* floor-based brackets */
>
> return -1
> ```

**second half of the algorithm**

> ```
> **ALGORITHM** *BinarySearch*(A[0...n-1], n, k) // appropriate for Add function
> //pre: A is sorted in ascending order, n is hte number of items in the array
> // K is the term being searched for
> //post: if successful, index is returned (1-based)
> // if the search is unsuccessful, the index of the current location is returned
> //what if n = 0? (that is, the first item is being added to the list)
>
>  f <-- 0 //0-based indices used in this method 
>  I <-- n-1 **
>  m <-- f + [(I-f)/2] /* floor-based square brackets */
>
> while (f <= I) do
>    // int comp = (*compare)(K, A[m])[function ptr]
>    if(K = A[m] ) // not-floor brackets, just subscript
>
>       // comp == 0, duplicate found, add here, adjust for 1
>       return (m + 1)
>    else if( K < A[m] ) // comp < 0
>       I <-- m-1
>    else
>       f <-- m+1
>    m <-- f + [(I-f)/2] // these are floor-brackets, but what is M in all this?
> return m+1 //Not found, but current mid position is the location to add
> ```

I understand most of it, but am having trouble translating some of his notation style. I'm not entirely sure what F, I, and M are all the time, or how they are totally applying.

Maybe 'F' is a function call being applied for the recursive nature of this algorithm?

This is a general template for variables being replaced by actual code objects and names, of course.

However, I tried looking up generalized templates of binary search algorithms, but I seem to be *bad* at finding proper example templates of certain method types. Especially on cplusplus.com, when looking up code gives me this advanced example that is in no way even TRYING to be an attempt at introducing a genenral concept of what a specific method or function does, generally, or what it always does or does not have.

So, could you help me parse what this pseudocode is saying? Maybe direct me to a good template of what a binary search algorithm template might be, to compare to this, to help me build the function body and definition?

Comment: when you say "template" you mean template in the general sense of being a blueprint, right? Note that C++ has templates that are something very specific and reading your text with that interpretation does not make always sense

Comment: Yeah. I'm mildly autistic, so I try to rely on "templates" being sample code as placeholders for what the body, prototype, and header of functions and classes look like **generally** while I try to become comfortable in a specific area of c++. Using that sample code, I can replace segments according to what a context demands. This is good in theory, but finding trully good sample code that serves that purpose, for me, can be difficult. 

The binary search algorithm might or might not be templated though. The class definition for SortedListArray is, but I'll corss that bridge later. :)

Comment: in that case it is better if you erase the word "template" from your c++ vocabulary until you learn what templates are in c++. Here in the question it is really confusing, because what I understood the question has little to do with templates

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet for examples.  You could use the keywords "C++ binary search example".

Comment: Both of these are *much* easier to understand if you draw a simple linear array on paper from left to right, fill it with an ordered sequence of your choosing, then draw up a variable table and start filling the values with quantities/values from/about your array. Finally, step through the algorithms and update the table as you go (`m`, `I`, `f`, etc.). The algorithms with take form and actually make perfect sense. It's stepwise, and exhaustive, but trust me; it will be worth it.

Comment: for( ; ; ; )
{
    string Templates = "sample code";
    return Templates;
}

Comment: Try replacing all those variable names with names that make sense. Note that you are looking for something in the array a, at an index somewhere between a lower bound f and an upper bound I.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews - for the last 2-3 years, I've tried googling such phrases for methods and such, and ironically enough, I get more stackoverflow threads than articles breaking down simple sample code examples. So, I go to these threads relating to whatever syntax I need help with, and they are almost always work-related questions, where the context is so specific, the code predicates on syntax that **wouldn't** be in the code I'd be using. Often enough, the program they are working on is so advanced, that I can't even try to reverse-engineer it to see what **would** be sample code material

Comment: A binary search is a common, standard, algorithm present in a lot of data structures books and in some C++ language books.  Is there a need to translate this algorithm, *again*?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews -- considering I **have** one of those data structures books, and it doesn't have a section on Binary Search Algorithms, and its not addressed in my **two** other c++ books, and I **couldn't** find a website that said, "Here is a binary search algorithm, typically you pass this to it, it receives this, and does these three fundamental things", then maybe yes, since I can't seem to find any of the **other** translations that you seem to claim just exist everywhere. Like, "Look they're in the trees, and in the air, and littering the sidewalk". Not where I'm stepping...

Comment: (first_index, last_index, or mid) (f, i, m) you whatever naming convention you thought easy.

Comment: "Data Structures and Algorithms in C++", 2nd edition, by Michael T. Goodrich, Chapter 10, examples in C++

Comment: Nah, my data struct book is "Data Abstraction & Problem Solving with c++: Walls and Mirrors". If there **is** an example on binary search algorithms, it isn't listed in the alphabetical index, its just discussed in soem chapter somewhere, and would require an irl binary search algorithm to find in the book. :3

That being said, thanks for hte help guys. I've managed to figure it out mostly. I have to figure out how I'm expected to implement and use these function pointers that I was told to create too, but that's another story.